# How to install Python in visual studio 2015

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

What I did is, I go to file->Project-> selected Pyhton to download. It showed the setup things. After that when I open the project is not working.

Please help if anything I need to add.
And it shows "We didn't find any interpreters".

Should I again download it.

Comment: a python interpreter needs to be selected to build python programs on VS

Comment: Please refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installation